# Как создать в интернет-магазине шаблон для карточки товара из определенной категории

Tags: laravel

Есть работающий интернет-магазин на Laravel, в котором надо создать создать новый шаблон для товаров из определенной категории. С чего мне как новичку в изучении Laravel следует начать? Документации по движку много - но мне не надо создавать сайт с нуля - пока от меня требуется создать шаблон и прикрутить его к товарам определенной категории. Нужна пошаговая инструкция.

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от реализации проекта, но в общем должно быть так:

Нужно найти контроллер который отвечает за вывод товаров это может быть `app/Http/Controllers/ProductController.php`.

Метод который выводит товар скорее всего `show()`. Разберись как работает данный метод.

Данный метод должен возвращать представление `return view('view_name')`. По сути это и есть шаблон страницы товара.

В методе show() ты можешь прописать условия при котором нужно использовать другой созданный шаблон.